# Retrieve Full Html Code in crystal report with full CSS

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have one website of tours management in which i have one crystal report which is generated from database and stored into one folder. now my question is that, i want to add one page full html code into that crystal report and then in pdf file it will be shown to me. i tried my best to get html body and even got but not with CSS so i need help very badly, how can i use full html body with CSS. Please help me out of this.

Advance thanks.

Comment: Post code for what you have done so far

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have got option, and there is only some of tag are supported in crystal report. so what i want is not possible by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are limitations in Crystal Reports, it appears that Crystal Reports only supports a small subset of HTML tags and attributes.

**The supported tags are:**

```
html
body
div (causes a paragraph break)
tr (causes only a paragraph break; does not preserve column structure of a table)
span
font
p (causes a paragraph break)
br (causes a paragraph break)
h1 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & twice default size)
h2 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 1.5 times default size)
h3 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 9/8 default size)
h4 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold)
h5 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 5/6 default size)
h6 (causes a paragraph break, makes the font bold & 5/8 default size)
center
big (increases font size by 2 points)
small (decreases font size by 2 points if it's 8 points or larger)
b
i
s
strike
u
```

**The supported attributes are:**

```
align
face
size
color
style
font-family
font-size
font-style
font-weight
```

From above my requirement was not possible to achieve.